# configure: error: *** POSIX caps headers not found when building SystemCtl on CentOS

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, makefile, configuration, centos

I am currently building a SystemCtl on an AWS EC2 instance following [this](https://linoxide.com/install-systemd-centos-redhat/) tutorial.

During the configuration step, I get this:

```
...
    checking for python... /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/python
    checking for python version... 2.7
    checking for python platform... linux2
    checking for python script directory... ${prefix}/lib/python2.7/site-packages
    checking for python extension module directory... ${exec_prefix}/lib/python2.7/site-packages
    checking for python lxml module... no
    configure: WARNING: *** python support requires python-lxml module installed
    configure: WARNING: *** python support not found, some documentation cannot be built
    checking for library containing dlsym... -ldl
    checking sys/capability.h usability... no
    checking sys/capability.h presence... no
    checking for sys/capability.h... no
    configure: error: *** POSIX caps headers not found
```

I am wondering what can be done to fix this as this prevents the `make` from starting.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you try following the directions in the tutorial you linked to for that error message?

Comment: `checking for sys/capability.h... no` → → Please install `libcap-devel` : Provides /usr/include/sys/capability.h

Comment: @KnudLarsen Too easy. I have checked, and it is already installed. I have also tried re-installing it.

Comment: @AnonCoward Of course. My system already has the `libcap-devel` installed.

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond, I ran the command you gave, received this back `/usr/include/sys/capability.h`. However, the original error still persists.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I think you should check the content of file `config.log`

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond What should I look for?

Comment: Well, if it were trivial, programmers would be left without livelihood. I think you should upload into some public place.